# How do I interpret weak exogeneity in an ADL model?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, ardl

First year econ graduate student here; looking at an ADL (Autoregressive Distributed Lag) model for the first time.

Consider $Y_t = \omega Z_t + \alpha Y_{t-1} + \beta Z_{t-1} + \mu + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t$ are iid normal. For consistent MLE estimation we need a "weak exogeneity" assumption on $Z_t$. In particular, if we say $(Y_t|Z_t, X_{t-1}, \dots, X_0)$ has density $f_\psi(y_t|z_t, x_{t-1}, \dots, x_0)$ and $(Z_t|X_{t-1}, \dots, X_0)$ has density $f_\lambda(z_t|x_{t-1}, \dots, x_0)$, we require that $\psi$ and $\lambda$ vary in a product space $(\psi, \lambda) \in \Psi \times \Lambda$.

1) Is this just a fancy way of saying that what value $\lambda$ takes may not affect $\psi$ and vice versa?

2) Does anyone have any help on getting an intuition for when this might be the case?

3) Do you know of any references that discuss this topic in more detail?